# Twitpic API from iPhone - pic posted but no URL returned?

Tags: ios, web-services, twitter

This is a weird one...

With the help of people here, I've got my iPhone app posting to TwitPic successfully - and when I first got it working, I could see an XML result being returned too...

But for some reason over the past two days, the API call seems to succeed - the pic appears on TwitPic - but... the response seems to be empty...

Anyone have any ideas? Seen anything similar? The code I use to invoke the API call is:

```
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease];

[request setData:twitpicImage forKey:@"media"];
[request setPostValue:username forKey:@"username"];
[request setPostValue:password forKey:@"password"];

// Initiate the WebService request
[request start];

// Need to find out how I can access the result from this call...

/* Result structure should be:

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <rsp stat="ok">
        <mediaid>abc123</mediaid>
        <mediaurl>http://twitpic.com/abc123</mediaurl>
    </rsp>
*/

// Check for errors
if ([[request responseHeaders] objectForKey:@"stat"] != @"ok"){
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"TwitPic Submission" 
                                                    message:[[request responseHeaders] objectForKey:@"mediaurl"]
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK!" 
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show]; 
    [errorAlert release];
}

NSString *twitpicURL = [[request responseHeaders] objectForKey:@"mediaurl"];

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"TwitPic Submission" 
                                      message:twitpicURL
                                      delegate:nil
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK!" 
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

I tried just dumping out `[request responseString]`... that's empty now also. That WAS showing a response, for sure.

As always, any help gratefully received. I'll give back once I'm able!

Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

OK, problem solved :-)

Check out this website: [link text](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#streaming)

Simply add these lines to your request:

```
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestDone:)];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestWentWrong:)];
```

and the following methods:

```
- (void)requestDone:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request { NSString *response = [request responseString];}
- (void)requestWentWrong:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request { NSError *error = [request error];}
```

NSString *response holds all the important feedback from twitpic.

Enjoy :-)

Comment: Also need to include `[request setDelegate:self]` for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

AH! I think I've found the problem. Seems to be a problem with TwitPic - 2 days ago I changed my password to a mixed-case one with numbers and letters. I just reset it back to an all lowercase one and... it all works fine.

I've sent a message to twitpic support - hopefully they'll look in to it!

Jamie.